# Count login attempts

Tags: php, security, symfony, bundle, symfony-2.5

I am looking for a bundle or a way on how to count login attempts of a user- (Im using FosUserBundle)
I was trying CCDN SecurityBundle, but it is already deprecated (Symfony 2.4 required).

Are there other stable bundles or ways to handle my problem ?

Comment: How about storing it in a `$_SESSION` with timestamps?

Comment: Not safe, you could clear the session when brute forcing.

Answer (score 4):

KEK's suggestion is not using Symfony at all.  You could [override](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) the `failure_handler` in your security configuration and create a service that will be called, then get the User and add to their number of failed attempts by storing that in the session or in the database directly.

Using this method you will also want to override the login success handler so that when the user logins successfully, you reset their number of failed login attempts back to 0 in either the session you were using or in the database.

Comment: Hi Jason. Yes thats why i did not respond anymore. He didn't read the thread well. I already did as you suggested, im storing the "fail logins" in a database table. Im just thinking right now, after how many attempts i should block the user account. My table, in which i save the failed attempts looks the following:id(int(11), ip_address (varchar 50), login_attempt_date (datetime), login_attempt_username (varchar 255)). I have these columns of the ccdn SecurityBundle. I just don't know yet under which criterias i should block a user account. Do you have any good ideas? Thank you Jason :)

Comment: Hey Jason, i've got a question on my dql statement. Is it 'secure' to check if the ip address is the same in let's say the last 5 attempts to login? " 'SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM UserBundle:SecuritySession s
                WHERE LOWER(s.login_attempt_username) = :username AND s.ip_address = :ip AND s.login_attempt_disarmed = 0 AND s.login_attempt_date >= :date'" . ":ip" always represents the ip address of the client who tried to login. Are brute force attackers using the same ip address or do they change their ip address each attempt?Would you delete the "AND ip" check?

Comment: That question is more of an opinion...in my own opinion, something like tracking IP addresses could be useful but shouldn't be completely relied on.  What I've done in the past is not base anything off of IP, just # of login attempts.  If the user has failed X number of times in say, the past X minutes, then I lock their account for a certain period of time.

Answer (score 3):

### Quick and easy

Store it in `$_SESSION` with timestamps and number of attempts. Increase the attempts after each failed login and clear it on success.

### A little more secure

Make a database table for `login_attempts`. It must contain at least a couple columns for identifying users (for example `ip_address` and `user_agent` or anything else to determine its unique) and a column for amount of login attempts (int).

Every time the user tries to login, increase the `amount_login_attempts`. After successfully logging in, reset the counter to 0.

### Sidenotes

- Temporary block the user if number of failed attempts is more than X
- Don't delay failed logins with `sleep()` as this uses server resources

Comment: Using `$_SESSION` in a Symfony environment will give you highly unpredictable and undesirable results.

Comment: yep. See the answer from Jason. +1 for reading the thread correctly and not voting it down, because of .. none sense :D